# "File not found" Error in a command from tkinter Button

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I'm creating a GUI using tkinter.
The GUI :

- asks the user which two csv files s/he wants to open
- then applies a treatment to these data. It's very long, for this question let's say it is called "test" and reads each file with pandas, then returns the first 5 rows of each file.

I've got a button called "Validate", I want it to apply "test" to the selected file I got from two Entry.get().
When I try to execute the file I get this error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'' does not exist: b''
```

I guess that has something to do with the path syntax - I'm on Windows so the paths of the files have backslashes.
I have tried to add the 'r' special character to get a raw string literal by various means, but it doesn't work (same error or sometimes it's `File b'r' doest not exist: b'r'`.)

What I find curious is that the error happens *before* I even select any file.
If I delete the command, the GUI works just fine.

Where does this error come from ? How can I fix it ?

I use Python 3.7.3 with Spyder 3.3.5 and IPython 7.6.1 on Windows 10

Here's my code (a bit long but already simplified):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button, Entry, filedialog as fd

def test(fileL, fileT):
    import pandas as pd

    df1 = pd.read_csv(fileL)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(fileT)

    return df1.head(5), df2.head(5)


class Selection:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.load_button = Button(master, text="...", command=self.loadFile)     
        self.filedir = Entry(master)    

    def loadFile(self):
        self.filename = fd.askopenfilename() 
        self.filedir.delete(0,"end")
        self.filedir.insert(0, self.filename)            

if __name__=='__main__': 

    #-------Defining the Root window
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1000x600+455+210")

    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

    #-------Defining the Frame  

    f2 = Frame(root, bg='#D5F4E4')

    f2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    f2.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
    f2.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)             
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)              
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1) 

    #-------Defining the Widgets
    TexteL = Label(f2, text="Please select file L :")          
    TexteT = Label(f2, text="Please select file T :")

    k = Selection(f2)  
    j = Selection(f2) 

    #--The said button--
    # To see how it looks like without bug, replace by just :
    # Validate = Button(root, text="Execute")

    Validate = Button(root, text="Execute",command=test(
            k.filedir.get(),
            j.filedir.get())
            )

    #-------Grid everything
    f2.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky="nsew")

    TexteL.grid(row=0,column=1)
    TexteT.grid(row=2,column=1)

    k.load_button.grid(row=1, column=2) 
    k.filedir.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew')

    j.load_button.grid(row=3, column=2) 
    j.filedir.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='ew')

    Validate.grid(row=3, column=2,sticky='nsew')

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should change `command=test(...)` of `Validate` button to `command=lambda:test(...)`.

Comment: `comman=` needs function name without `()` and arguments - it is called "callback". In `command=test(k.filedir.get(), j.filedir.get()))` you runs function `test()` at start and its result assign to `command=` - You can use `lambda` to resolve this problem `command=lambda:test(k.filedir.get(), j.filedir.get()))`

Comment: It worked ! Thank both of you :)
Both of you gave me the solution but I find furas's is more explicit. @furas can you put it as an answer so that I can validate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`comman=` needs function's name without `()` and without arguments - it is called `"callback"`.

In code

```
command=test(k.filedir.get(), j.filedir.get()))
```

function `test()` is executed at start (even before you see window) and its result is assigned to `command=` - so you also get `command=None`

You can use `lambda` to resolve this problem - it creates function without variables

```
command=lambda:test(k.filedir.get(), j.filedir.get()))
```

or you would have to create function in normal way

```
def some_function():
    test(k.filedir.get(), j.filedir.get())

Button(..., command=some_function)
```

In `tkinter` callbacks are used in `command=callback`, `bind(event, callback)` and `after(time, callback)`

---

Doc: [Button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm), [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)